# Changing element's display from 'none' replays its animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Watch the below snippet, and you'll notice that the sliding animation plays twice—once when the `.addClass` statement executes, and a second time when `#test`'s `display` is set to `initial` (timeouts are set to help see the issue):

```js
$(() => {
  $('#test').addClass('animate');
 
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#test').css({ display: 'none' });
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#test').css({ display: 'initial' });
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#test {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

#test.animate {
  animation: move 1s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
  100% {
    left: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="test" src="https://cdn4.buysellads.net/uu/1/3332/1524843316-62666.png">
```

**Why does changing an element's `display` attribute from `none` to one that is visible (`initial`, `block`, etc.) via JavaScript cause an animation assigned to the element to replay, and how can I disallow it from doing so?**

Note: having the `animation-fill-mode` set to `forwards` is a requirement.

Comment: According to [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/#example-dee38741), "If an element has a display of none, updating display to a value other than none will start all animations applied to the element by the animation-name property, as well as all animations applied to descendants with display other than none."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `animate` class after the first animation is completed.

```js
$(() => {
  $('#test').addClass('animate');
 
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#test').addClass('pause').css({ display: 'none' });
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#test').css({ display: 'initial' });
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#test {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

#test.animate {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: move 1s ease forwards;
}

#test.animate.pause {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    display: none;
    left: 100px;
  }
  1% {
    display: inital;
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="test" src="https://cdn4.buysellads.net/uu/1/3332/1524843316-62666.png">
```

Comment: The point of `animation-fill-mode` being `forwards` is so that the element would keep the attributes it received from animating (in this case, the image would stay towards the right). I suppose I can remove the `animate` class while simultaneously adding a class which gives the image the proper attributes. Or is there a better way?

Comment: @SpyderScript i've added a little hack to achieve so. :)